# self host sentry config.yml on email and smtp

Tags: python, ubuntu, sentry

i have installed sentry on my server self hosted using the instructions with thier installer .
now my problem is that sentry is not sending mail and when i refer to this doc :

```
https://develop.sentry.dev/self-hosted/email/
```

they say you must change the `config.yml` file i have searched every where for this file but i could not find it . does any one knows how and where i can probably change email setting to send email .
i even searched for config.yml in thier docker compose file but all i could find was this :

```
  symbolicator:
    <<: *restart_policy
    image: "$SYMBOLICATOR_IMAGE"
    volumes:
      - "sentry-symbolicator:/data"
      - type: bind
        read_only: true
        source: ./symbolicator
        target: /etc/symbolicator
    command: run -c /etc/symbolicator/config.yml
  symbolicator-cleanup:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using docker?
For starters you can check `/etc/sentry/config.yml`

Also rememeber that according to the docs

> Once you change your configuration, you'll need to restart all Sentry services by running docker-compose restart web worker cron sentry-cleanup (or just docker-compose restart to restart everything).

You can also do `docker ps` to find the correct sentry container and do `docker exec -it <container-name-or-id> <shell-executable>` to enter the container's shell, once inside you can do `ls -lah` or `ls -lah /etc/sentry` to see if you can find the config file.

Add the docker tag if you're using docker so someone whit more knowledge can help you out.